# Jquery show span on hover the image

Tags: jquery

Hi i have here an `<ul>` tag with `<li>` and `<img>` inside and a `<span>` below for the description of each image.

```
<ul id="thumbs">
<li>
<img src=".jpg" class="imgme"/>
</li>
<span>
Description
</span>
```

I want my span to be displayed on hover the image.

I am using this jquery but seems like not working:

```
$(function() {
   $(".imgme").hover(function() {
    $(this).next("span").show("slow");
    },function(){
    $(this).next("span").hide("slow");
   });
  });
```

Can you show me an example wherein the span will slide down if image is on hover. Thanks

Comment: Don't you want the span inside your LI? That would make MUCH more sense, and then your script would work.

Comment: Im sorry i was wrong about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`img`'s parent `li`'s next is `span`.

```
$(function() {
   $(".imgme").hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().next("span").show("slow");
    },function(){
    $(this).parent().next("span").hide("slow");
   });
  });
```

Or you could bind the event handler on `li`.

```
  $(function() {
   $("#thumbs > li").hover(function() {
    $(this).next("span").show("slow");
    },function(){
    $(this).next("span").hide("slow");
   });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(".imgme").next("span")` - this gives nothing because there is no element next to `img`

Try this

```
<ul id="thumbs">
    <li>
        <img src="Images/1003057.jpg" class="imgme" />
        <span>Description </span>
    </li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".imgme").hover(function () {
            $(this).next("span").show("slow");
        }, function () {
            $(this).next("span").hide("slow");
        });
    });   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go bit more simpler/different: **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/csB6w/4/

`.next` api: http://api.jquery.com/next/

`.toggle` api: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Also I have hidden the description to start with, **And** in case you put the span inside the li see **demo** here: http://jsfiddle.net/W7AZb/

If it fits the need, `:)`

**code**

```
$("span").hide();
$(function() {
    $(".imgme").hover(function() {
        $(this).parent().next("span").toggle("slow");
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i have done complete bins for above issue. you can check demo on codebins too.

**Demo link:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7v

**HTML**

```
<ul id="thumbs">
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.ctspanish.com/quiz/animals/dolphin_swim_md_wht_6133.gif" class="imgme"/>
  </li>
  <span>
    Dolphin
  </span>
  <li>
    <img src="http://futureshine.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/jumping-monkey-gif-animation.gif" class="imgme"/>
  </li>
  <span>
    Jumping Monkey
  </span>
</ul>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $(".imgme").hover(function() {
        $(this).closest("li").next("span").show(500);
    }, function() {
        $(this).closest("li").next("span").hide(400);
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
ul{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
#thumbs li{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
#thumbs span{
  display:none;
}
```

**Demo link:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7v